# How to Wait until one promises complete even if some rejected or still in progress?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am working with node.js application using puppeteer
I have some list of XPATH that may be page included
and I can't wait only for one of them because it may be not included in this page and I want to wait until only one of them to shows up

so I was wondering if it is possible to wait until only one of them resolved even if the other was rejected or even not complete.

please if you have an answer show some codes

Comment: Promise.allSettled ?

Comment: @enno.void I think Promise.allSettled will wait until all resolved/rejected but as I mentioned I want to resolve all if only one is resolved

Comment: Promise.race()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you need `Promise.any()`:

https://v8.dev/features/promise-combinators#promise.any

https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-85#javascript

However, you can use it unflagged only with last [Node.js canary versions](https://nodejs.org/download/v8-canary/) that use V8 85.

With Node.js v14.6.0 or [nightly](https://nodejs.org/download/nightly/), you need `--harmony-promise-any` flag.